# C# Selenium - How to find out if a radio button is selected

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to see if a radio button is selected for a test in Selenium.

I can click on the button no problem, but I can't read if it has been selected or not. The HTML looks like this:

[radio button code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mr1Me.jpg)

I have tried rdioBtn.selected but it always comes back as false.

I can't see a checked element.

How can I tell if it is selected or not?

Thanks

Comment: You can select and un-select button multiple time to observe the change of HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can try by using javascript executor like below.

```
IJavaScriptExecutor executor = (IJavaScriptExecutor)Constants.WebDriver;
bool isChecked=(bool)executor.ExecuteScript("return document.getElementsByName('communication-pref')[0].checked;");
```

change the "[0]" with index of whichever radio button you are trying to test.